# How does a web browser decide on an entry point among the files it receives from a server?

Tags: javascript, html, browser, webserver, entry-point

**Situation:** Say I type some website's URL into my search bar. The server sends some HTML and CSS files to my computer.

**Question:** How does my web browser decide which file among the received files is the entry point (or otherwise "starting point") from which to start evaluating/rendering?

**What I've tried**: Googling various phrases and doing a cursory search on SO. But my search terms might've been suboptimal, and this question might seem stupid, because *I don't know what I don't know.*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The browser initially requests exactly *one* thing from the server: the path requested. For example, for this page here, the request is to:

```
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65366695/how-does-a-web-browser-decide-on-an-entry-point-among-the-files-it-receives-from
```

That path can be considered to be the entry point. Then, inside the response:

```
view-source:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65366695/how-does-a-web-browser-decide-on-an-entry-point-among-the-files-it-receives-from
```

, it finds paths to *other* resources to download. For example, this page has:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.sstatic.net/Js/stub.en.js?v=95d1ce093683"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.sstatic.net/Shared/stacks.css?v=50b8afc7d7a9">
```

in the source code of the HTML response. These resources are then downloaded by the browser.

Other parts in the HTML, CSS, and JavaScript may initiate downloads as well, but it'll all ultimately stem from the initial HTML file requested (which may have been done by the user typing in an address, or by clicking on a link).

Comment: I'm still confused. For example, if the website's root has a file named `index.html`, then presumably, this file is accessed when we visit the site's homepage (or is it? Please correct me if I'm wrong). Yet, maybe the URL we requested was for `[somesite].com` rather than `[somesite].com/index.html`. In that case, how would the browser "know" that the file we really want is `index.html`? In other words, how does the browser know to access `index.html` even though we've never explicitly told it to access that file?

Comment: @Asker, the brower doesn't know. The server has ( but is not _required_ to have) code that sends `index.html` with a header that says its content is `text/html` in response to a request from a browser for `[somesite].com` without identifying the resource it wants. Ultimately this question is off topic, but try "[How the web works](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/Getting_started_with_the_web/How_the_Web_works)" on [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/).

Comment: @Asker It depends on the server configuration. It may serve you the index.html page if that's the way it's set up, or it may be configured to serve something else.

Comment: @traktor I had already read that before asking, but it didn't seem to address my question directly. (Skimmed again just now.) Thanks to your and CertainPerformance's comments, I understand clearly now that the choice of file(s) to send is made by the server. But I wonder "May the server send *several* resources at once, in response to the *same* HTTP request?" If so, then the browser must have a way of distinguishing an entry point among the several resources it receives. Yet this wasn't mentioned, so would I be correct to conclude that the server only sends one resource per HTTP request?

Comment: @Asker I don't think so - one request corresponds to exactly one response at most (with the exception of server-sent messages through websockets). You can look at your browser's network inspector to see examples.

Comment: On your recommendation, I used network inspector on a web app whose server-side code (Node.js + Express) uses `express.static('build')` to send the front-end, where `build` is a folder with some front-end code. The `build` folder had several files, but only one HTML file, `index.html`. That file was the response to my homepage GET request... yet there were multiple other files in the folder. So somehow, the server "knew" to choose to send `index.html`, the sole HTML file. What if there happened to be two HTML files, `index1.html` and `index2.html`, rather than only one?

Comment: @Asker Servers will often, by default, serve `index.html` if it exists. If it doesn't exist - eg, if you have `index1.html` and `index2.html` instead - the server will probably give a 404 page instead.

Comment: @Asker refer to the `index` property of the options object passed to [`express.static`](http://expressjs.com/en/4x/api.html#express.static). This causes express to search  for `index.html` by default when no file is specified in the request URL, but can be configured to search for a different file name, or not searching for a file at allt by setting `index` to `false`